Powershell Exchange-Online - Set-Mailbox HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled with cert based auth
The cmdlet Set-Mailbox does not accept the parameter HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled if the cmdlet "Connect-ExchangeOnline" is cert based.
With my admin credentials the parameter is shown.
Already tested the following permissions in Office 365 Exchange Online:

Contacts.ReadWrite
Exchange.ManageAsApp
full_access_as_app
MailboxSettings.ReadWrite
PeopleSettings.ReadWrite


Did you assign Microsoft Entra roles to the application?

Yes - did not work. Final solution was to add the app to the exchange administrators :/

Exchange Administrator is a Microsoft Entra role. Glad my comment fixed your issue.
